# Vector shape thinning

Tags: image-processing, 2d, vector-graphics

I am looking for an algorithm for computing vector shape skeletons. The restrictions follows: shape is the result of subtraction of closed paths, represented by segments cubic/conic splines, Bezier curves and line segments, and thats why can contain holes.

If shape represented as raster connected component there are many ready-to-manufacture algorithms and implementations such are Zhang-Suen, P. Kwok, 3-4 distance transform and even C implementation in Graphics Gems IV "Binary Image Thinning Using Neigborhood Maps".

So the question: is there an algorithm that having vector input computes vector skeleton in a clean manner, without having rasterizing path, thinning it and converting back to vector representation?

Addendum: Is there any mathematical morphology stuff dealing with vector shapes?

Comment: Could you post an example of your vector shape?

Comment: Here is encapsulated PostScript sample file: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_L82eoraNOTNkNhdURqWGJlYU0

Comment: Neither Google Docs nor Word can open that document for me. Please post a link to the rasterized version of the document.

Comment: Here is it https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_L82eoraNOTY01nTmd3cFFTc0U

Comment: Google Docs opened nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! I guess when one has to take a look at vector graphics images and how they are coded. In this case i will pick [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) which basically codes lines, polygons, points so that they could be redrawn or re-rendered at a higher resolution. Thus for any image which is properly constructed using a SVG editor or a vector graphics editor - one is basically encoding the shapes and lines to be redrawn.

Thus to the ends of actually obtaining a skeletonization which is also a SVG obtained from an SVG one would have to replicate the polygon recoding process and the perform the skeletonization on the space of polygons, and thus recode the resulting set of lines which form the skeleton. This in the computer graphics community basically gives you a [Straight Skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton)! This would produce a skeleton in any scaling!